# Sign with RSA-1024 an SHA-256 digest: what is the size?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, sha

I was wondering:
1) if I compute the digest of some datas with **SHA-512** => resulting in a hash of 64 bytes
2) and then I sign this hash with **RSA-1024** => so a block of 128 bytes, which is bigger than the 64 bytes of the digest

=> does it mean in the end my signed hash will be *exactly* 128 bytes?

Thanks a lot for any info.

Answer (score 9):

With RSA, as specified by [PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125), the data to be signed is first hashed with a hash function, then the result is *padded* (a more or less complex operation which transforms the hash result into a modular integer), and then the mathematical operation of RSA is applied on that number. The result is a *n*-bit integer, where *n* is the length in bits of the "modulus", usually called "the RSA key size". Basically, for RSA-1024, *n* is 1024. A 1024-bit integer is encoded as 128 bytes, exactly, as per the encoding method described in PKCS#1 (PKCS#1 is very readable and not too long).

Whether a *n*-bit RSA key can be used to sign data with a hash function which produces outputs of length *m* depends on the details of the padding. As the name suggests, padding involves adding some extra data around the hash output, hence *n* must be greater than *m*, leaving some room for the extra data. A 1024-bit key can be used with SHA-512 (which produces 512-bit strings). You could not use a 640-bit key with SHA-512 (and you would not, anyway, since 640-bit RSA keys can be broken -- albeit not trivially).